# Odd exception terminology "throwing up"

Tags: exception, throw

Not that it's of groundbreaking importance or anything, but I commonly see people refer to forwarding an exception out of a method to the caller as throwing "up," when technically it is being thrown downward in the call stack, right? Is this just some programmer humor or what? Or is the call stack envisioned as growing down?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Stacks traditionally grow downward in memory, so call frames deeper on the stack are at higher addresses, so the exception moves "up" the stack.

Answer (score 4):

The call stack is often viewed as growing down. Likewise, when memory layouts are drawn as pictures, address 0 is often at the top.

Of course, it could also all be just a sick joke. :)